# How to {get,set} values of a dropdown list which contains Enums?

Tags: c#

I have a dropdown list which contains 2 Enums. This is my dropdownlist.

```
<asp:DropDownList Width="75px" ID="ddlPilotDefaultSync" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

I have a set of enums in SyncRequestTypeEnum.cs class.

```
  public enum SyncRequestTypeEnum
{
    ProjectLevel = 1,
    //DBLevelSync = 2,
    FullSync = 3,
    DifferentialSync = 4
}
```

I binded these enums to my dropdownlist using HtmlEncodeHelper.

```
 ddlFactoryDefaultSync.DataSource = HtmlEncodeHelper.HtmlEncode(value);
 ddlFactoryDefaultSync.DataBind();
```

Now I want to get the selected value and set the selected value for the drop down list.

```
public int FactoryDefaultSyncId
{
    get
    {

    }
    set
    {

    }
}
```

Can Someone help on this?

Comment: Cast the enum to int and back

Comment: I tried but its giving an error. can you writet the code here?

Comment: Can you write the code on how you are making the conversion? And what does the value stand for in this statement: HtmlEncodeHelper.HtmlEncode(value)

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: HtmlEncodeHelper.HtmlEncode(value) in this value means i m getting all the enums into that value.

Comment: One more thing what I faced is after binding in the UI I am unable to see the values. The Values I saw in the UI are System.UI.row

Comment: This is how I tried to get and set values
 public int FactoryDefaultSyncId
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)Enums.SyncRequestTypeEnum.    (ddlFactoryDefaultSync.SelectedValue);
        }
        set
        {
            ddlFactoryDefaultSync.SelectedValue = Convert.ToString(value);
            lblFactoryScheduleDesc.Text = Convert.ToString(value);
        }
    }

Comment: @user3356020 You should edit your answer instead of writing this to the comments.